# LDAP Query C# With Windows Server Essentials Role Office 365 mailnickname

Tags: c#, email, ldap

I have a legacy application that used LDAP query to get back the mail address and use Web Services of Exchange to send the message.  I have added support for Office 365 and was able to use our corporate test account to pull up the users mail address and log into Exchange online.  Now I set up a Server 2012 Domain controller and found out there is a new role called Windows Server Essentials and allows you to easily sync with Office 365 and assign local users to Office 365.  What I found out though is the LDAP query returns null for any user because the email field in AD local is not populated.  What I would like to ask what is the formal or best practice for this situation where AD locally does not have a local exchange so when using office 365 the email field is not populated when you assign a user to office 365 for mail with the Essentials role.  I know I can use the UserPrincipalName but my LDAP query has mailnickname in the search query which means any user without an email they will not be returned in the LDAP query.  I just would like to maybe see if anyone knows the proper way, and please don't tell me to query exchange because that would involve a lot more work than just updating the legacy calls to LDAP.  LDAP Query below.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(mailnickname=*)(samaccountname=usernamevaluehere)(objectCategory=person))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(mail=*)(samaccountname=usernamevaluehere)(objectCategory=person))
```

The "mailnickname" attribute is specific to Exchange. The "mail" attribute is the "E-mail" field in Active Directory, and is not specific to Exchange.

Comment: That does help but when you do a new domain controller and use that role in 2012 and assign a user to office 365 for mail the mail field in AD locally does not get populated.  Is it standard practice to use dirsync with the role from 2012?  I mean if a admin sets up a user in the role would they then go back into local AD and update the mail field?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Office 365, but I am with AD. Try the proxyAddresses attribute then. That normally contains all the user's email addresses (it's an array, but you can still do proxyAddresses=*). According to [this](http://enterpriseit.co/office365/create-email-alias-dirsync/) it seems to get updated by Office 365.

Comment: My proxyaddress attribute is empty for the user that has an email assigned in the essentials role.  This is a fresh AD role added to a Fresh Server 2012 that I added one user to office 365....I just don't know how to support  this if it's done this way, I may not be doing the best practices approach but should I be using dirsync with Azure to get my email field pulled down to local AD?

Comment: I couldn't say. I have no experience there. We use AD and Exchange here at my work, and that's all I have experience with.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know if it's better to go straight to exchange for the user information or still use LDAP.

Comment: I would use LDAP. You can only talk to Exchange via PowerShell, which means running PowerShell commands from C#, which I've done for creating new mailboxes, but it's a pain. Avoid it if you can.